# Compare two real sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

Do you have any idea to solve the following problem?

Let $c \in(0,1)$ and consider two sequences $(x_k)_{k\geq 1}$ and $(y_k)_{k\geq 0}$ defined by $x_1=y_0=c$,
\begin{eqnarray*}
x_{k+1}&=&\frac{(n-2k)c}{n-k} + \frac{k}{(n-k)x_k}  \quad \textrm{for } k\geq 1; \\
y_k &=& f(k/n) \qquad \textrm{for } k\geq 1,
\end{eqnarray*}
where 
$$f(t)=\frac{c(1-2t)+ \sqrt{1+(c^2-1)(1-2t)^2}}{2(1-t)} \quad \textrm{ for } t\in(0,1).$$
Prove that for all $1\leq k \leq n/2$
$$y_{k-1} \leq x_k \leq y_k.$$
Note that $f(t)$ is the positive solution of the equation
$$x=\frac{c(1-2t) }{1-t}  + \frac{t}{x(1-t)}.$$
Using R, I observed that the result holds. But I need a mathematical proof for my research.

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I would like to close this topic. I am now able to prove this problem by induction. Thank you.

Comment: You can write a self answer if you managed to solve the problem.

Comment: Yes.  To prove the induction step, I used the mean value theorem and some bounds on the function f and its derivatives.

Comment: By a self answer, I mean, click on the "Answer This Question" button (or something like that) (a warning will pop up), and type your answer.